# CURL (23) Failure writing output destination

Tags: curl, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I've got some problems with starting my first blockchain network in Hyperledger Fabric. You know that there's a tutorial how to build a test network, but when I'm trying to download Fabric (repository) with using a link in tutorial (curl -sSL *** bush -s), I get a message:
*curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination.* Sometimes it's written smth like *0!= 2415*. I've read that it could be related with the access restrictions to the folder but nothing has changed after my changes. I'm new in Blockchain practice so I really need your help. What should I do? Thank you!
p.s

- curl version 7.75 (downloaded from the official site; has a path directory in the system configuration)
- OS Win 10 x64
- docker version 20.10.5 (latest)
- docker-compose version 1.28.5 (latest)
- Python, Go and NPM are the latest also